# URL Alias does not work in Menu-Blocks with i18n (pathauto also installed)

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n, blocks

I'm currently facing a problem with Internationalization and the main menu block on my page.

So when I created the page about-anna and navigating to /de/about-anna - it works great also with /node/27 it works. Thats ok.

But the menu-item is instead of /de/about-anna just /node/27

So I continued testing, added the english-translation and setabout-anna as path alias again. But the problem still exists.

I also looked up the internet and Drupal Answers and I found some good answers... but didn't fix my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was still testing and found another bug, that when your browser is in german, you can't switch to english.

---

So in Configuration > Languages > Detection and Selection (admin/config/regional/language/configure) I unchecked "Browser" from the list.

Now the menu-block uses path aliases too and you can switch languages on the site.