# Menu doesn't link to alias URL

Tags: routes, path-aliases

I'm having difficulty on a fresh Drupal installation getting the menu to use an alias (let's say "foo") rather than "node/#" link. The alias works when I type it straight into my browser. When creating the menu, I specified the alias (foo) but it automatically applies the system path to it.

The message that comes up is:

```
The menu system stores system paths only, but will use the URL alias for display. home has been stored as node/1
```

This doesn't come up as an error, rather just an information dialogue.

For this installation I did a minimal install as I wanted it to be a fairly simple website. I've never done this before so there were a few modules I had to enable to get it working how I wanted. I'm thinking maybe there's a module or menu setting that isn't enabled by default using the minimal install.

I'm not using any language packs, and none of the solutions on the following questions were successful (most revolve around languages.)

- [URL Alias does not work in Menu-Blocks with i18n (pathauto also installed)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33975/url-alias-does-not-work-in-menu-blocks-with-i18n-pathauto-also-installed)
- [How do I use URL aliases in menus?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/how-do-i-use-url-aliases-in-menus/2353#2353)

Comment: This is normal behavior, does the menu link redirect you to foo or node/# when navigating ?

Comment: Hi Pan. If hover over the menu link it will show "node/#" etc. If I click on the link it will display "node/#" in the URL bar. However I can manually type the URL that uses the alias into my browser and it shows the same page, without redirecting (the URL in the browser still shows the alias.)

Comment: Interestingly, it started working properly on my "main menu" but a custom menu I have created still links to the system path not the alias.

Comment: hmmm thats weird i guess you need pathauto module maybe?

Comment: I continued to work on the site figuring I'll fix it later. Turns out I think it's the way I implemented this menu caused it to use the non-alias link. All my other menus seem to work fine. I'll update this post later with how I did it and what to do instead in case anyone else comes across this problem (it's fairly unique though.) Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: +1 for pathauto - I don't know how I lived without it! The functionality it provides should almost be a core module I reckon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) Module.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Pathauto module](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) for this.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.

For more detail about this module you could read the READMe.txt of this module.